# Javascript Async=true Attribute

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I see this code sample in a certain unnamed vendor's documentation.  It appears to load a script asynchronously, then invoke a function from it thereafter.  I realize that the if-undefined check will prevent an overt error, but is this not totally incorrect?

I believe that in IE8/9 it will work properly but block execution until the LOADER_URL script loads and executes; and I believe in many other browsers that do support the async attrbute, this will simply result in the inline-block executing the code inside the if-block only part of the time.  The documentation states "tags are asynchronous and do not slow the loading of your pages."

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="LOADER_URL" async="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof (OBJECT_DEFINED_IN_LOADER_URL) != "undefined") { OBJECT_DEFINED_IN_LOADER_URL.Load(false); }
</script>
```

Looking at an earlier version of their documentation, it did not have the suggestion of the async attribute and did not make this claim.  Did some technical writer make a mistake and say "yeah, that'll work" without testing adequately in all browsers?  In IE <= 9 it will work all the time.  And since async code is uber-fun to debug ... maybe it worked for them ...

That's my suspicion :)

Comment: any code you would like to share?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to escape the lts and gts and the angry data-escaping monsters ate my tags.

Comment: @JaimieSirovich, you should just indent the code by 4 spaces, and all characters would be escaped automatically. I've fixed it for you for now.

Comment: @Dogbert I totally never knew that.  Maybe I should use SO more =)  I just lurk most of the time 'stealing' free knowledge that saves me hours and hours of time.

Comment: why `<br>` after the `<script>` statement? xD

Comment: I did that before I realized what @Dogbert fixed.  I'm removing it.

Comment: Yes, I believe the inline script may very likely not execute most of the time. That's the meaning of "asynchronous".

Answer (score 14):

You were correct to be suspicious. The posted code is pretty much guaranteed to not work as intended in browsers supporting the async attribute.

Basically there are 3 "modes":

1. If the async attribute is present, then the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available.
2. If the async attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.
3. If neither attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

Source: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html

Note: The async attribute value is ignored, the mere presence of the attribute indicates that the script should be executed asynchronously. So setting the value to false will still be the same as setting it to true.

Answer (score 4):

**if async is true**

The script will be downloaded and executeed as soon as possible and HTML page will be parsing simultaneously

**in case of async is false**

The process of script downloading and execution will be carried out before starting of any HTML page parsing hence HTML pasing will halt while script is downloaded and executed first.

Answer (score 3):

"Async=true", when supported by browser, basically means: browser will load script asynchronous and will execute it when it prefer.
So there is no garantee that the second script will be executed after the first one.

You can safely use "asynch js load" only if you don't have, in page, any other code directly using objects you are loading in the asynch script.

I have evidence of all that, because I made a similar error in one of my project, but it will not be easy to replicate via fiddler or something similar.

So the code as proposed in the question will work sometime yes, sometime not.

Comment: async=true is not valid syntax. Just use async to enable it in IE10 and above.
Source: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html

Comment: @user1491819 the page moved to here http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/script.html — the correct syntax is no `async` attribute, `async` by itself (HTML), or `async="async"` (HTML and XML). This is what most Boolean attributes work in HTML. Unfortunate that some people introduce attributes that accept true or false. It makes the whole thing confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As described [*here*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp), it is New in HTML5: **async attribute** assigned by  'async' as its value  Specifies that the script that is executed asynchronously (only for external scripts).

I found no problem so far on my site with this code in any browsers to call external script:

```
function include(src, attr, value)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.setAttribute(attr, value);
    script.async = 'async';
    script.src = src;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

include('LOADER_URL', 'custom-attr', 'custom-value');
```

Comment: According to MDN, the `async` attribute is `boolean`, so does `script.async = 'async';` work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async Or is it one of those weird ones where the value on matters if it is `false` and all others are assumed `true` just because the attribute exists?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this makes sense heavily depends on the structure of the code.

You have to keep in mind that the browser caches certain files (and this includes scripts). Your scripts seems to be some kind of Library which loads required resources on demand (perhaps something similar like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)), so this async code may make perfect sense, if the browser has everything in cache ( = the object is already there) to just interrupt the loading process.